# The change in value of opacity is not reflected in the app

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to make a video player. I am displaying rows of icons button on top the video using `Stack()`. I want to make those icons disappear like in YouTube mobile app after a certain amount of time.

I have used the `AnimatedOpacity()` widget but the icon remain on screen if I set them visible and invisible if set them invisible from the start.Their opacity never changes.Can anyone guide me please?

```
Positioned.fill(
  child: AnimatedOpacity(
    opacity: _isVisible ? 1.0 : 0.0,
    duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
    child: GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          _isVisible = !_isVisible;
        });
        // Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 4), () {
        //   setState(() {
        //     _isVisible = false;
        //   });
        // });
      },
      child: Container(
          height: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width /
              _controller.value.aspectRatio),
          width: double.infinity,
          child: PlayerControls(controller: _controller)),
    ),
  ),
)
```

I expected the icons to disappear after 3 seconds, but that didn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that:

```
            double opacityLevel = 1.0;

            Positioned.fill(
              child: AnimatedOpacity(
                opacity: opacityLevel,
                duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() => opacityLevel = opacityLevel == 0 ? 1.0 : 0.0);
                    // Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 4), () {
                    //   setState(() {
                    //     _isVisible = false;
                    //   });
                    // });
                  },
                  child: Container(
                      height: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width /
                          _controller.value.aspectRatio),
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: PlayerControls(controller: _controller)),
                ),
              ),
            )
```

Comment: I tried giving color to the container and then when i tapped on it the color dissapeared but the icons were not showing even though the opacity was 1.

Comment: Can you try to change the container with the GestureDetector? Put the GestureDetector as child of the container

Comment: It looks like the builder of the PlayerControls is not rebuilding because when i put a placeholder widget in it's place it dissappeared only when clicked on the icon, not the container. I also tried moving all of this to the PlayerControls widget, near the row icons widgets but the same problem still presisted.

Comment: One thing you could do that will work for sure is passing the opacityLevel to PlayerControls as parameter. And user this opacity to hide the icons inside of the PlayerControls widget. Its not the cleanest solution IMO but it will do the trick